# How to decompress pbzip2 data in memory buffer by using libbz2 library in C++

Tags: bzip2, compression, libzip

I have a working version of decompressing bzip2 data where I call the bz2_bzdecompress API. It goes something like this

```
while (bytes_input < len) {
    isDone = false;

    // Initialize the input buffer and its length
    size_t in_buffer_size = len -bytes_input;
    the_bz2_stream.avail_in = in_buffer_size;
    the_bz2_stream.next_in = (char*)data +bytes_input;

    size_t out_buffer_size =
        output_size -bytes_uncompressed;  // size of output buffer
    if (out_buffer_size == 0) {  // out of space in the output buffer
      break;
    }

    the_bz2_stream.avail_out = out_buffer_size;
    the_bz2_stream.next_out =
        (char*)output +bytes_uncompressed;  // output buffer

    ret = BZ2_bzDecompress(&the_bz2_stream);
    if (ret != BZ_OK && ret != BZ_STREAM_END) {
      throw Bzip2Exception("Bzip2 failed. ", ret);
    }

   bytes_input += in_buffer_size - the_bz2_stream.avail_in;
   bytes_uncompressed += out_buffer_size - the_bz2_stream.avail_out;

    *data_consumed =bytes_input;

    if (ret == BZ_STREAM_END) {
      ret = BZ2_bzDecompressEnd(&the_bz2_stream);
      if (ret != BZ_OK) {
        throw Bzip2Exception("Bzip2 fail. ", ret);
      }
      isDone = true;
    }
  }
```

This works great for native bzip2 compressed files, but for pbzip2 (Parallel Bzip2) and "Splittable" bzip2 data, it throws a "BZ_PARAM_ERROR".

I see that pbzip2 in their documentation says this-

> Data compressed with pbzip2 is broken into multiple streams and each
>   stream is bzip2 compressed looking like this:
>   [-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----]
>
> If you are writing software with libbzip2 to decompress data created
>   with pbzip2, you must take into account that the data contains
>   multiple bzip2 streams so you will encounter end-of-stream markers
>   from libbzip2 after each stream and must look-ahead to see if there
>   are any more streams to process before quitting.  The bzip2 program
>   itself will automatically handle this condition.

Source:http://compression.ca/pbzip2/

Can someone please tell me how to handle this? Should I be using some other libzip2 API?

Also, pbzip2 files are compatible with the normal "bunzip2" command. How is that bzip2 handles this gracefully while my code throws a BZ_PARAM_ERROR?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your `BZ2_bzDecompressEnd()` you need to call `BZ2_bzDecompressInit()` again (you must have called it initially before that loop), if there is still data left to decompress, i.e. `bytes_input < len`.

To decompress each of the `|-----|` blocks, you need to do an `init`, some number of `decompress` calls, and an `end`.  So if you still have input left, then you need to do another `init`, *n**`decompress`, `end`.

Make sure that you do a final `end`, in order to avoid a big memory leak.

You're getting a `BZ_PARAM_ERROR` because you are trying to use an uninitialized `bz_stream` to decompress. Once you do `BZ2_bzDecompressEnd()`, you can't use that `bz_stream` any more, unless you do a `BZ2_bzDecompressInit()` on it.

Comment: I have been trying hard to understand this but I couldn't even see a sample anywhere. It would be great if you could additionally point me to some sample where I can see how people handle this.

Comment: Also, thanks a lot for the quick response. I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. I do this in the constructor, 
`int ret = BZ2_bzDecompressInit(&the_bz2_stream, 0, 0);`
`if (ret != BZ_OK)`
 `{ throw Bzip2Exception("Failed initialize", ret);`
 `}` 
Are you suggesting I do this again? right after I'm done with the while loop? or right after I make the bz2Decompress call?

Another question is, if I *only* have more data left to decompress, why is bzDecompress call returning a BZ_PARAM_ERROR? That part still doesn't make much sense to me. Thanks again :)

Comment: I've been trying to get it done the way you explained but I'm not sure how to find out the "n" number of times that I have to run decompress for. Can you please point me to an example? Or help me with some sample code? Thanks

Comment: Until you have consumed all of the input.